# Can not dismiss NavigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uipresentationcontroller

Hello guys I have a problem to close my NavigationController. 
This piece of code is not working for me. When I try to call it in my ViewController

```
   @IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.navigationController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

This is what I am doing in my first ViewController I just open the ProfileViewController which have a custom transition.

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let controller = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "Profile") as? NavigationControllerTransition
controller?.modalPresentationStyle = .custom
controller?.transitioningDelegate = self
controller?.interactor = self.interactor
controller?.animatorDirection.direction = .right
self.animatedTransition.animatorDirection.direction = .right
self.present(controller!, animated: true, completion: {})
```

I have a custom NavigationController Class which calls NavigationControllerTransition to make it happen to swipe from the edge from the screen for the custom transition.

```
class NavigationControllerTransition: UINavigationController {

    var interactor: Interactor?
    var animatorDirection = AnimatorDirection()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let panGesture = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(NavigationControllerTransition.handleTap(sender:)))
        self.view.addGestureRecognizer(panGesture)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func handleTap(sender: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {

        let percentThreshold: CGFloat = 0.3
        let translation = sender.translation(in: view)

        var horitonzalMovement: CGFloat = 0.0

        var downwardMovementPercent: Float = 0.0

        if self.animatorDirection.direction == .left {
            horitonzalMovement = -(translation.x / view.bounds.width)
            let downwardMovement = fmaxf(Float(horitonzalMovement), 0.0)
            downwardMovementPercent = fminf(downwardMovement, 1.0)

        } else {
            horitonzalMovement = +(translation.x / view.bounds.width)
            let downwardMovement = fmaxf(Float(horitonzalMovement), 0.0)
            downwardMovementPercent = fminf(downwardMovement, 1.0)

        }

        let progress = CGFloat(downwardMovementPercent)
        guard let interactor = interactor else { return }

        switch sender.state {
        case .began:
            interactor.hasStarted = true
            dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        case .changed:
            interactor.shouldFinish = progress > percentThreshold
            interactor.update(progress)
        case .cancelled:
            interactor.hasStarted = false
            interactor.cancel()
        case .ended:
            interactor.hasStarted = false
            interactor.shouldFinish ? interactor.finish() : interactor.cancel()
        default: break
        }
    }
}
```

So I can swipe to open or close my ViewController and the transition works great. The only problem is when I try to close my ViewController using a UIButton. The NavigationController will no dismiss and freeze. Any tips ? :(

Comment: You can just hide the navbar using    `navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)`

Comment: I don't want to hide it I want to dismiss it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to assume that you're just trying to dismiss the ViewController and not the navigation controller itself. In that case your IBAction should look like this.

```
@IBAction func backButtonPressed(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
    // Technically you don't even need the self here. 
    // In swift self is implicit in most cases. 
}
```

Think of a Navigation controller as handling a stack of views. When you segue to a new view within the navigation controller, you add a new view to the stack. When you dismiss you pop one off of the stack. Also never segue to go back, always dismiss. If you fail to dismiss a view controller on the stack the view controller will just remain in memory.

[Here is a good tutorial on the subject.](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/ios-from-scratch-with-swift-navigation-controllers-and-view-controller-hierarchies--cms-25462)

If you need to pass data back to the previous view one technique is called an unwind segue. [Read up on that here.](http://ashishkakkad.com/2015/04/work-with-unwind-segue-in-swift-language-ios-8/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: Which file is your IBAction located in?

Comment: In my viewcontroller

Comment: Is the ProfileView the one with the back button that you're trying to dismiss? In that case the IBAction needs to be in the ProfileViewController.

Comment: Also is the IBAction actually firing? Did you link it up to the button in the storyboard?

Comment: It's already in the ProfileViewConrtoleller..Yeah it's firing

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117491/discussion-between-bargangilo-and-bilalreffas).